# How to update values for all children of Firebase Node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've created an app that registers and logins users with Firebase Authentication and also stores all registered users in Database like in this image:

[image]

after registration the users `signedIn` value is `false`. if the user logs-in the value of the `signedIn` field for that specific user changes to `true` like this:

```
mDbRef.child(mAuth.getUid().toString()).child("signedIn").setValue(true);
```

How do I go about upon starting my app or restarting the app all users `signedIn` value is set to false? I will update it when a user signs out but if the app is closed without user signing out the value of `signedIn` in database stays true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication sign-ins are persistent across app restarts.  When the user closes an app, it does not sign them out.  Sign out only happens explicitly when you call the signOut API.  The user is also effectively signed out if they uninstall the app or somehow delete their auth token.

If you want to record something about the user's session, Firebase Auth will not be helpful to you.  You will have to record the beginning and end of that session on your own, and you might have the force the session to end on your back if the user kills the app.